# Problem in creating a calculated field in Google looker studio due to aggregation types

Tags: looker-studio

I have the following data set:
Each row of data includes: date (a date), representative (email address), Sales ($ value)
I have also added another field called days active (that counts the number of days the representative was active).

I want to calculate the average sales per representative per day so I tried creating this calculated field:
Sales/count_distinct(representative)/days active
(I use count_distinct to get the number of representatives)

Looker gives me the following error:
"Sorry, calculated fields can't mix metrics (aggregated values) and dimensions (non-aggregated values). Please check the aggregation types of the fields used in this formula."

I also tried using CAST but I get the same error:
Sales /CAST(count_distinct(representative) as NUMBER)/CAST(Days active as NUMBER).

In google sheet it works like a charm :)